# Store Scraped data to a text file in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am able to scrape data using Beautifulsoup and now looking to generate a file containing all the data from which I scraped using Beautiful Soup.

```
file = open("copy.txt", "w") 
data = soup.get_text()
data
file.write(soup.get_text()) 
file.close()
```

I don't see all the tag and entire content in the text file. Any Idea on how to achieve it?

Comment: `get_text()` will only return the text from the HTML document. Also, you should open a different file to write to. From the looks of it you are appending the soup output to the end of the file you started with.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
with open("copy.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

if you have a list of URLs that will be scraped and then you want to store each URL scraped in a different file, you can try:

```
my_urls = [url_1, url_2, ..., url_n]
for index, url in enumerate(my_urls):
    # .............
    # some code to scrape 
    with open(f"scraped_{index}.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: It worked :) I have one more enhancement to do - I want to store each URL scraped in different file - this stores in single file. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Chai check now, if this is useful you can accept the answer! thx!

Answer (score 0):

**Quick solution:**

You need to just convert the soup to string. Using a test site, in case others wish to follow:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

r = requests.get("https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone")
soup = BS(r.content)

file = open("copy.txt", "w") 
file.write(str(soup))
file.close()
```

**Slightly better solution:**

It's better practice to use a context for your file IO (use `with`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

r = requests.get("https://webscraper.io/test-sites/e-commerce/allinone")
soup = BS(r.content)

with open("copy.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```